# Why "adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth" doesn't work correctly when setting lineBreakMode as "NSLineBreakByCharWrapping"?

Tags: ios, uilabel

```
UILabel *aLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 150, 200, 50)];
aLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
aLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:13];
aLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
aLabel.text = @"start 中文字符是这些 12345678901234567890 asdfghjkla12345678901234567890 asdfghjkla中文字符是这些 12345678901234567890 asdfghjkla中文字符是这些 12345678901234567890 asdfghjklasdfghjkl end";
aLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
aLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
aLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByCharWrapping; //NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail
[self.view addSubview:aLabel];
```

If you run this code, it will not auto resize font.
But if you use the default value `NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail` of `lineBreakMode`, it will auto resize font but the line breaks at a not proper way.
So here is the question, how can I use `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth` and `NSLineBreakByCharWrapping` together?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `numberOfLines` to a non-zero number in order for it to work.

Comment: tks, but it doesn't work too if set `numberOfLines ` to a non-zero number. eg.5 or 10000.